# Ubuntu MATE 15.10 - Cannot recognize my monitor through DisplayPort

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 15.10, displayport

I'm rather new to Linux, please keep that in mind when answering my question.

I am dual-booting Ubuntu MATE 15.10 next to my Windows 10 OS. On Windows, my two monitors work fine side-by-side. DisplayPort is recognized (most of the time) and so is my second monitor. I am using a BenQ GW2765HT for my main monitor, which is a 27" 2560 x 1440 60hz monitor and an old 24" Acer something for my secondary monitor.

I am using an nVidia GTX 970, I am using the drivers that I selected from the "Additional Drivers".

When I installed Ubuntu MATE, I just used my secondary monitor (through HDMI) so everything was fine, but then when I plugged in my main monitor - it wasn't recognized.

Please tell me what information you require from me, so that you guys can start helping me.

P.S, I have Google'd this issue for a couple of hours now. I've seen a lot of threads about this problem, but none of them yielded any fruit. Hence I made a new post.

Cake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the nvidia card can't figure out the EDID of your monitor. You can try creating a manual entry for it in */etc/X11/xorg.conf*

Can you open "nvidia-settings"? To be able to save it to a xorg.conf file, you will need to open it as root.

**Press Alt-F2**, then type '**gksudo nvidia-settings**'. Type your password, and then the settings window will open. Select '**X Server Display Configuration**' on the left. See if you can't activate the screen from there. But the most important part will be to '**Save to X Configuration File**'.

Next you will want to post in your question the output of your xorg.conf.

Open a terminal and paste:

> cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Highlight the text that came out and right-click and 'Copy' it. Now paste it as part of your question. That will give us more information on how to help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.

I have opened the settings, like you said. I only have two 'tabs' inside of it. One named "Applications Profiles" and the other "nvidia-settings Configuration".

In the latter, I have an option to click "Save current configuration", which I did. 

When I copy and paste what you told me to, in the Terminal, I receive the following error: 
`cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if your nvidia-settings is installed. Run 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings'. Then try again with what I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @G Trawo, I ran the command you just listed. It returns  "newest version is already installed". I did a quick google search, I've read that it does not automatically come with a xorg.conf nowadays. I can generate one though, would you like me to do that?

Comment: Yeah. xorg.conf doesn't get made anymore. But in your case you may have to create one to write some modesets (EDID) for your monitor. The quickest way to create one is to use nvidia-settings and then edit it to suit.

Comment: Will you be able to guide me through the process? Or should I do a google search to "Add EDID Ubuntu"?

Comment: http://arachnoid.com/modelines/ has a calculator that can be used to create the modeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32376/discussion-between-g-trawo-and-cake).